# Connection between field and the frobenius homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let K be a field with char(K)>0.

How do I prove that every algebraic extension of K is a separable extension if and only if $\phi:x \rightarrow x^p$ is surjective ?

Comment: Hello, this is only one direction and it seems for me that the assumptions are not the same in the other question.